vim re-orders files for :next
When using vim's :next command to edit a list of files, if any files have the .log extension, they're put at the end of the argument list.  I never noticed this before, using vi/vim for 35 years.  I tried a few other extensions and only .log seems to be affected.
:n a.log b c.txt d e
:args
[b]   c.txt d     e     a.log

This doesn't happen if I specify the files on the command line; only if I use :n or :args xxx.
This happens for vim version 8.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.
My options:
:set
--- Options ---
  background=dark     langnoremap         ruler               ttimeout            wildmenu
  display=truncate  nolangremap           scroll=18           ttimeoutlen=100
  history=200       nomodeline            scrolloff=5         ttyfast
  incsearch           nrformats=bin,hex   showcmd             ttymouse=sgr
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  printoptions=paper:letter
suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc

Why is vim re-ordering the files?  How can I get it to stop doing this?

So what's the question?

Doesn't happen here with $ vim -Nu NONE. If it does for you, can you share your vimrc?

@romainl Thanks for the suggestion.  It doesn't happen with -u NONE, but still happens even if .vimrc is empty and .vim is missing.  -N doesn't affect it.  It doesn't happen even with -u ~/.vimrc.  So, -u does more than --help says.

-u is a red herring. Could you add the whole output of :set (executed in a normal Vim session where you have that issue) to your question?

Did you perhaps modify anything in $VIMRUNTIME? Did you put your .log file ordering in the system runtime files?

set suffixes is the ticket, thanks.  .log is in the list.  No idea where that got set.  -u wasn't a red herring at all, since it gave me a way to compare a working case with a nonworking case.  Put suffixes in an answer if you want the points.

$VIMRUNTIME isn't set in my environment, and I don't know what "system runtime files" refers to.  I didn't change any defaults in /usr/lib, just using standard Ubuntu 22.04 vim support.

$VIMRUNTIME is only set in Vim. If you want to know where suffixes is set, do :verbose set suffixes in Vim.

What romainl says. Do :echo $VIMRUNTIME and it will show you where the system runtime files reside. It's /usr/share/vim/vim91 on my Arch box. See :help vimfiles if you want to know the whole story. Sometimes people change stuff there and then they're surprised if Vim behaves strangely. Not that it matters, it was just a red herring after all.

/usr/share/vim/vim82/debian.vim:set suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc  thanks!

Thank you for the edit, it tremendously improved your question. In fact, I can reproduce the behavior with Vim 9.1 with suffixes including .log and not when it doesn't.

The fix is to remove .log from suffixes.
Apparently, vim reorders files passed by :next or :args based on the suffixes setting.  Vim's help says:
:help suffixes
For file name completion you can use the 'suffixes' option to set a priority
between files with almost the same name.  If there are multiple matches,
those files with an extension that is in the 'suffixes' option are ignored.
The default is ".bak,~,.o,.h,.info,.swp,.obj", which means that files ending
in ".bak", "~", ".o", ".h", ".info", ".swp" and ".obj" are sometimes ignored.

That doesn't explain re-ordering, especially in the case where the basename doesn't match and filename completion isn't being used, but changing the value of suffixes to omit .log solves my issue.
The default isn't necessarily as stated above, because it often gets set in platform-specific initialization.  To see where it was set, use
:verbose set suffixes


"The default isn't as stated" - yes. it is. A distribution-specific runtime file isn't "the defaults". Instead, do :set suffixes&. While your :!grep will work, you could also use Vim's built-in :grep or - much easier, more accurate and handed to you on a silver plate by romainl - :verbose set suffixes. I could not reproduce the re-ordering but all the reproducible information in this answer is either wrong or awkward. I downvoted because of these inaccuracies.

@Friedrich The :help test says default is ".bak,~,.o,.h,.info,.swp,.obj" which is not accurate, so I stand by my statement that the default isn't as stated.

@Friedrich Next time I spin up a fresh VM I'll see if I can reproduce this on Ubuntu with no personalization.  I'd be interested to know whether you can reproduce this with .log in your suffixes list.

@Friedrich Thanks for the reminder about :verbose set suffixes.  I edited my answer accordingly.

On defaults: I see where this is coming from: you refer to your debian.vim runtime file as the defaults whereas Vim talks about a hard-coded, compiled-in default value. That's what you set with :set suffixes& (trailing amp), see :help :set-default. Do this, print the value and you'll see that it's exactly what :help suffixes says. Your debian.vim is owned by Debian, not by Vim.

Right, so my edited remark about that is better than what I said originally.  Thanks.
